# using yaml in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, yaml

I'm looking to create my own yaml files inside the zend framework for static objects.  I don't want to replace the application.ini file.

I have added the following file inside configs

application/reports.yaml

```
reportInfo:
  team_a:
    some_var: some_var
    some_var_1: some_var1
  team_b:
    some_var: some_var
    some_var_1: some_var1
```

How do I get the value of reportInfo inside say the index controller?

```
$reportInfo = Zend_Get_YAML ('configs/reports.yaml') // or something similar this is a guess
print_r($reportInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried?

you can do it with [Zend_Config_Yaml](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.yaml.html) or sfYaml::dump or [the new yaml component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/yaml.html)

try this in your controller:

```
$config = Zend_Config_Yaml::decode(file_get_contents(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/reports.yaml',
));
print_r($config);
```

Comment: its saying that it cannot find the yaml.php file?